# How to simplify linear algebra equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Im a trying to understand the derivation of an linear algebra equation. It is from a paper about 3D mbICP scanmatching. I am not that good at linear algebra but I am trying to learn.

The equation they start with is

$ (\delta + U(p1)r)^T(\delta+U(p1)r)+L^2\theta^2$

Here U(p1) is a 3X3 skew-symetric matrix and $\theta=r^Tr$

Then they derive it to

$r^T(U^T(p1)U(p1)+L^2I)r-2\delta^TU^T(p1)r+\delta^T\delta$

The part I dont understand is how they get $-2\delta^TU^T(p1)r$

I tried to derive it myself and I got to this:

So the multiplication that creates the $-2\delta$... is based on

$\delta^TU(p1)r + (U(p1)r)^T\delta = \delta^TU(p1)r + r^TU(p1)^T\delta=\delta^TU(p1)r + (\delta^TU(p1)r)^T = \delta^TU(p1)r + -(\delta^TU(p1)r) = 0$

$(\delta^TU(p1)r)^T =-\delta^TU(p1)r $ because U is skew symetric (not sure about this due to the multiplication with delta and r)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply out in the obvious way, you get, among other things,
$$\delta^TUr\quad\hbox{and}\quad r^TU^T\delta\ .$$
If you look carefully at the dimensions of these terms you will see that they are both $1\times1$ matrices (that is, in effect, they are scalars), and therefore have to equal their transpose.  So we get
$$\delta^TUr\quad\hbox{and}\quad \delta^TUr\ .$$
So these add up to give $2\delta^TUr$, and since $U$ is skew-symmetric this is $-2\delta^TU^Tr$.

Comment: Thank you, so if I understand correctly you transform the right one ($r^TU^T\delta$) to $(\delta^TUr)^T$ and because they are scalars $(\delta^TUr)^T$ = $(\delta^TUr)$

Comment: That's right.${}$